# Inheritance in Javascript calling functions

Tags: javascript

somehow JS inheritance doesn't get in my head. I tried quite a few things now and for some reason I cannot add a method to an object that inherits.

See my try of defining `B.setC` that then is not available later somehow. Any hints?

cheers
Tom

```
A = function( value){
        this.aValue = value;
}


B = function(value){
    A.call(this, value); 
    this.bValue=value+value;
}

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);//subclass extends superclass


B.setC = function(value){
    this.c = value+value+value;
    console.log("execution");
}

B.prototype.setD = function(value){
    this.D = value+value+value+value;
    console.log("execution");
}





 x = new B("ConstructorParam");
x.setC("methodParam");// gives that setC is not a function
x.setD("methodParam");// works but I added setD to A not B
```

Comment: It's just a typo, you meant `B.prototype.setC = ...`, but you have `B.setC = ...`

Comment: Actually it isn't a typo. I want to add setC to B not A and if my understanding is right and to what I saw debugging in Chrome it is if I use B.prototype.setB then I add setB to the prototype of B aka A and not B . Or am I missing sth?

Comment: Your code is also falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my blog)*: Declare your variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confusion seems to come from this misunderstanding; quoting your comment:

> Actually it isn't a typo. I want to add setC to B not A and if my understanding is right and to what I saw debugging in Chrome it is if I use B.prototype.setB then I add setB to the prototype of B aka A and not B . Or am I missing sth?

which is also shown by this comment in the question:

> ```
> x.setD("methodParam");// works but I added setD to A not B
> ```

`B.prototype` is not `A`. `B.prototype` is an object that has `A.prototype` as its prototype. You correctly added `setD` to `B.prototype`; it isn't in any way added to either `A` or `A.prototype`.

If you want to use `setC` and `setD` the way you showed, you would put them either on `B.prototype` (so they are accessible on instances of `B`) or on `A.prototype` (so they're accessible on instances of `A` or `B`).

If we change `B.setC =` to `B.prototype.setC =`, make `d` lower case to match `c`, add some missing `var`s, and use shorter values when creating and calling the methods, we get this:

```
var A = function( value){
    this.aValue = value;
};

var B = function(value){
    A.call(this, value); 
    this.bValue = value + value;
};

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);//subclass extends superclass

B.setC = function(value){
    this.c = value + value + value;
    console.log("execution");
};

B.prototype.setD = function(value){
    this.d = value + value + value + value;
    console.log("execution");
};

var x = new B("b");
x.setC("c");
x.setD("d");
```

Just after the last line of code, this is what we have in memory (minus a bunch of unnecessary details):

```
         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
         |                                                               |
         \ +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                                             |
A−−−−−−−−−>|   function    |                                             |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                             +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
           | prototype     |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>|   object    | |    
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                           / +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |    
                                                       | | constructor |−+
                                                       | +−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
         +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
         |                                           | |
         \ +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                         | |
B−−−−−−−−−>|   function    |                         | |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ | |
           | prototype     |−−−>|      object      | | |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  / +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ | |
                              | | constructor      |−+ |
                              | | setC: (function) |   |
                              | | setD: (function) |   |
                              | | [[Prototype]]    |−−−+
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  | +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
x−−−−−−−−−>|    object     |  |
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
           | aValue: "a"   |  |
           | bValue: "aa"  |  |
           | c: "ccc"      |  |
           | d: "dddd"     |  |
           | [[Prototype]] |−−+
           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

`[[Prototype]]` above is the name the spec uses for the "internal slot" of an object that contains its reference to its prototype object. In contrast, `prototype`, the property on functions (e.g., `A.prototype`), is just a normal property of functions that points to the object that `new` will use as the `[[Prototype]]` of the new object it creates if you use that function with `new`.

---

Just for completeness, here that is in ES2015+:

```
class A {
    constructor(value) {
        this.aValue = value;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor(value) {
        super(value); 
        this.bValue = value + value;
    }

    setC(value) {
        this.c = value + value + value;
        console.log("execution");
    }

    setD(value) {
        this.d = value + value + value + value;
        console.log("execution");
    }
}

let x = new B("b");
x.setC("c");
x.setD("d");
```